# Liquibase: Does not honor schema name for H2, but MySQL is fine

Tags: java, spring, maven, h2, liquibase

- I am using `maven cargo` to deploy my `Spring` application.
- I am trying to run this against `MySQL` and `H2` embedded database.
  The configuration for `H2` looks like

> ```
> @Configuration
> @Profile("development")
> public class H2DatabaseConfig extends JpaCommonConfig {
>     @Override
>     public DataSource dataSource() {
>         // (todo: harit) get rid of hard coding
>         System.out.println("This is H2 Database Profile");
>         final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
>         dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
>         dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test_common");
>         dataSource.setUsername("sa");
>         dataSource.setPassword("");
>         return dataSource;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected Class<? extends Dialect> getDatabaseDialect() {
>         return H2Dialect.class;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected Properties getJpaProperties() {
>         final Properties properties = new Properties();
>         properties.setProperty(HBM2DDL_AUTO, Hbm2ddlType.CREATE_DROP.toValue());
>         properties.setProperty(SHOW_SQL, TRUE.toString());
>         properties.setProperty(FORMAT_SQL, TRUE.toString());
>         properties.setProperty(USE_SQL_COMMENTS, TRUE.toString());
>         properties.setProperty(CONNECTION_CHAR_SET, getHibernateCharSet());
>         properties.setProperty(NAMING_STRATEGY, ImprovedNamingStrategy.class.getName());
>
>         return properties;
>     }
> }
> ```

and for `MySQL` it looks like

```
@Configuration
@Profile("default")
public class MySqlDatabaseConfig extends JpaCommonConfig {
    @Override
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // (todo: harit) remove hardcoding to read from environment variables
        System.out.println("This is MySQL Database Profile");
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_common?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Dialect> getDatabaseDialect() {
        return MySQL5InnoDBDialect.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties getJpaProperties() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(HBM2DDL_AUTO, Hbm2ddlType.UPDATE.toValue());
        properties.setProperty(SHOW_SQL, TRUE.toString());
        properties.setProperty(FORMAT_SQL, TRUE.toString());
        properties.setProperty(USE_SQL_COMMENTS, TRUE.toString());
        properties.setProperty(CONNECTION_CHAR_SET, getHibernateCharSet());
        properties.setProperty(NAMING_STRATEGY, ImprovedNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

When I run Integration tests using cargo, I see two differences,

1. When ran against `MySQL` the schema name is taken care when Liquibase runs, I see **test_common**

> ```
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Dropping Database Objects in schema: test_common.test_common
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Reading from test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Reading from test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Reading from test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
> ```
>
> test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Table network created
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: ChangeSet
>   liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2 ran successfully in 8ms
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
>   test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
>   test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: ChangeSet
>   liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2 ran successfully in 6ms
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
>   test_common.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:18 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

1. When ran against `H2`, It applies on **PUBLIC** schema and **not** on **test_common**

> ```
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Dropping Database Objects in schema: TEST_COMMON.PUBLIC
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
> ```
>
> PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Table network created
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: ChangeSet
>   liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2 ran successfully in 5ms
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
>   PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
>   PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into
>   network
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: ChangeSet
>   liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2 ran successfully in 5ms
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from
>   PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
>       INFO 5/26/14 9:45 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase tries to handle both "schemas" and "catalogs" where the catalog is the top most container which may or may not contain schemas. For databases like MySQL which have just one level of object groupings, "catalog" and "schema" are interchangeable. For H2, you can have both the catalog/database and also schemas within the database. Your h2 setup is using the test_common database, but the default PUBLIC schema within that database.

If you are wanting to configure Liquibase to use a non-default H2 schema, use the "defaultSchema" SpringLiquibase configuration property.