# H2: how to set default schema and database?

Tags: database, spring, h2, liquibase

I am using `Liquibase` for my database updates and testing it against `H2`.

I am using `Spring` to configure the properties. I use

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test_common");
```

to connect to `test_common` database, but it did not work out.

I realized that in `H2` `database != Schema`, so I tried to put a default schema to `test_common` as

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test_common;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA test_common\\; SET SCHEMA test_common");
```

but this didn't work out, I see logs as

```
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Dropping Database Objects in schema: TEST_COMMON.PUBLIC
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Table network created
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: ChangeSet liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2 ran successfully in 5ms
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into network
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into network
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into network
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into network
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into network
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: New row inserted into network
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: ChangeSet liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2 ran successfully in 5ms
INFO 5/26/14 2:24 PM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-2.xml::05192014.1525::h2: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
```

How do I set default schema and database name in H2?

Comment: Why don't connecting to `test_common` db work? Does your code do programmatic lookup of the db/schema name?

Comment: Yes, it does, using `@Configuration` class in `Spring Framework`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874693/liquibase-does-not-honor-schema-name-for-h2-but-mysql-is-fine

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Default schema is `PUBLIC`

For the record, the [`Commands`](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html) page of the H2 Database site for the [`SET SCHEMA`](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_schema) command says:

> The default schema for new connections is `PUBLIC`.

That documentation also notes that you can specify the default schema when connecting:

> This setting can be appended to the database URL: jdbc:h2:test;SCHEMA=ABC

## Only one database

As for accessing various databases, H2 does not support the SQL Standard concepts of `CLUSTER` or `CATALOG`. You connect to one specific database (catalog) as part of your JDBC URL. Connections to that database are limited to that one single database. See the Question, [Can you create multiple catalogs in H2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25088998/642706) with an Answer by Thomas Mueller.

You could open another connection to another database but it would be entirely separate.

So talking about a “default database” has no meaning with H2 Database.

Comment: You can also create the schema if it doesn't already exist as part of the connection URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225700/can-i-have-h2-autocreate-a-schema-in-an-in-memory-database

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are interacting with Liquibase through the Java APIs. There is a `setDefaultSchemaName()` method on the Database object that you can use to set a different default schema.