# Can you create multiple catalogs in H2?

Tags: jdbc, h2

When you connect to an embedded local H2 database like so:

`jdbc:h2:./target/data/CATALOGA;`

H2 uses the database name (CATALOGA here) as the CATALOG_NAME. This can be seen by querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CATALOGS table.

Is it possible to have more than one catalog?

You cannot insert into the INFORMATION_SCHEMA and H2 does not allow for `CREATE CATALOG` statements.

---

Background information is that we have queries that join across catalogs. So something that looks like:

```
select * from CATALOGA.dbo.example e
    inner join CATALOGB.dbo.example2 e2 on e.fk = e2.fk
```

The queries have catalog/schema in them directly and I need to be able to execute them on H2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For H2, a catalog is a database. In H2, you can create multiple schemas within a database, but not multiple catalogs.

Of course you can create multiple databases, but I guess that's not what you want, because databases are independent. You can link a table in another databases using the ["create linked table"](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_linked_table) feature, but the linked table is still in the same schema.

Comment: I noticed the linked table feature but the docs say only simple selects are possible. I think then it will not work in my scenario since I need to join on them correct?

Comment: I wonder, where in the docs did you read that only simple selects are possible? That sounds like a documentation bug. It's true that joins may not be as efficient as when you execute them in the real database, but joins are possible (and updates, deletes, inserts).

Comment: I think I may have mis-interpreted the statement. The [Linked Tables](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#linked_tables) section says `Only simple statements are executed against the target database, that means no joins.` I took that to mean you can't join to a linked table.

Comment: I see. I will update the documentation and add "queries that contain joins are converted to simple queries"

Comment: I wonder if it's at all possible to have schema names with a period? I'm in the same situation. A vendor is using OpenEdge with supplamental databases that are qualified with pub.mfg. trying to setup a development db with h2.

Comment: @BrettRyan no, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @BrettRyan The SQL standard says quite explicitly that a period is the delimiter between a catalog and schema and table/etc. (For example, section 5.4 “Names and identifiers” in SQL 1992.) Crazy to put in a schema name.

Comment: So, in formal language… the answer is that of the `CLUSTER` > `CATALOG` > `SCHEMA` > `TABLE` hierarchy defined by the SQL standard, H2 defines the last two (schema & table). The currently open database is the one and only database available in the context, so effectively no `CLUSTER` or `CATALOG` (current db is implicitly *the* catalog).

Comment: Yeah, was just being hopeful. I think that for some of us we use h2 for a test development db for a production and qa db that supports multiple catalogs. It would be very handy to somehow replicate this even if it wasn't a true catalog.